# how to upload multiple decoded base64 images in php?

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to send multiple base64 images to PHP web service. Now i need to decode all those base64 images and save them into upload folder.

This is my code for assigning base64 values into a hidden input type.

**html:**

```
<form action="./upload.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="imagefile1" name="imagefile[]" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="imagefile2" name="imagefile[]" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="imagefile3" name="imagefile[]" value="">
</form>
```

Unfortunately, this method does not work I do not know where is the problem!

**upload.php:**

```
$imagefile = $_POST['imagefile'];
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads/');
foreach($imagefile as $i => $imagefiles)
{

    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $imagefiles[$i]);
    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[$i]);
    $image_type = $image_type_aux[$i];
    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[$i]);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
    file_put_contents($file[$i], $image_base64[$i]);

}
```

Comment: Is not there anyone to help me?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using bad index `$i` in your local variables :
In the lines below, you're using `$i` instead of using the right index.

```
$image_type = $image_type_aux[$i];
$image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[$i]);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
file_put_contents($file[$i], $image_base64[$i]);
```

But I think you should use something like this (but you should tests with your values) :

```
$image_parts = explode(";base64,", $imagefiles[$i]);
$image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[1]); // [1] instead of [$i]
$image_type = $image_type_aux[1]; // [1] instead of [$i]
$image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]); // [1] instead of [$i]
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
file_put_contents($file[$i], $image_base64); // remove [$i] from $image_base64[$i]
```

Comment: Hi @EngNowruzi , please add a `var_dump()` of a `$imagefiles[$i]` in your question.